# Is there a double dissociation between face and object processing?

Tags: perception, vision

We know of the condition called prosopagnosia in which the processing of faces is impaired. Is there a condition in which the processing of faces is intact and the processing of objects is impaired, which would prove a double dissociation, which would further prove the independence of these two processes.

Comment: I am a bit confused with your question. "processing faces" involves processing objects, the object being the face.  Can you please elaborate on the question?

Comment: There is evidence that the processing of faces is distinct from processing objects. One of them is the so called face inversion experiment in which participants are unable to recognise inverted faces, but are able to do so with objects. The other evidence is the mentioned prosopagnosia. So, no in terms of higher level vision faces are not the same as objects. I want to know if there is an example where object processing is impaired and face processing is intact.